# Maintainable automatic mail system

Tags: php, email, templates, template-engine

Rather an advanced question.

The application of our company sends a number of emails to our users. Some are send daily, some  weekly, ... The emails are in "standard" company format and contain text that is (partially) loaded from the database. The text is for example dependent of the language of the user.

> How can I build this system, so it would be easy to maintain?

Right now, the emails are created in a PHP script:

- The script selects the users from te database that need to receive a mail.
- It creates the email text, using data from the database (eg: $text = "Dear ".$user['Username'])
- This text is parsed with PHP templates. The template contains the default layout.

But if we want to adjust something small to the emails, I have to do it in the code. Which is not my job, people from marketing would prefer being able to do this directly..

Any ideas on how to pull this of technologically, in a performant maintainable way?

Comment: Have you considered outsourcing it to a proper email company, such as MailChimp? They have an API so you can connect it to your database, but companies of that kind know how to send email reliably, and take all the hassle out of it.

Comment: Seems nice! I was hoping for some open source library, but this would do :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if i get your point you could have the text for the mail template stored in the database.
When somebody wants to change the content, they could have a front-end where they do their preferred changes in.

Comment: I could do that, but what about the data that comes from the databank? For example the $user['Username'] above?

Comment: Where you edit your email template you just write some special strings (%USERNAME%, %DATE%, etc) that will be replaced. Do a string_replace in your code and change  %USERNAME% with $user['username'] etc.